# How to access cfg file in KARAF/etc using PAX-CDI

Tags: osgi, karaf, pax

How to access cfg file in KARAF/etc using PAX-CDI

eg:

KARAF_HOME\etc\import.cfg

How to use it using
@OsgiServiceProvider

Comment: Those *.cfg files are usually treated as configurtations for configuration admin. 
As you are already running in an OSGi environment, it's best to stick to the way that works, so just let the configuration admin do the configuration of your CDI object. 
Also best to ask at either one of the involved communities, like karaf and ops4j. Both do have mailinglists, you'll get proper feedback there.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I am trying not trying to modify existing configuration i am trying to access new cfg added specific to my bundle

Comment: The same applies to that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An work around you can you DOSGI to load and place the property in a Util and you access in you Pax-CDI code

**DOSGI**:

```
@Component(immediate = true, configurationPolicy = ConfigurationPolicy.REQUIRE, configurationPid = "ca.esc.pbm.frontend.security")
public class SecurityConfig{

public static final String TOKEN_SIG_SECRET = "signatureSecret";

@Activate
    private void activate(BundleContext bundleContext, Map<String, ?> properties) throws Exception {

        logger.info("Security Config Activated");

        Properties props = new Properties();

        if (properties.isEmpty()) {
            throw new ComponentException("Config Properties is Empty ");
        }

        logger.info("Property loaded " + properties.size());

        props.putAll(properties);

        PropertiesUtil.setProperty(props);

        System.out.println(properties);

    }
}
```

**Property Util**

```
/**
 * Property Util to load the *.properties form class path
 * 
 * @version 1.0
 */
public class PropertiesUtil {

private static Map<String, String> propertiesMap;

/**
 * Get the property value for the given key from the loaded property
 * 
 * @param name
 * @return String
 */
public static String getProperty(String name) {
    return (String) propertiesMap.get(name);
}

/**
 * Set the property value for the given key from the loaded property
 * 
 * @param props
 */
public static void setProperty(Properties props) {
    Map<String, String> propertiesMapLocal = new HashMap<String, String>();

    for (Object key : props.keySet()) {
        String keyStr = key.toString();
        propertiesMapLocal.put(keyStr, props.getProperty(keyStr));
    }

    propertiesMap = propertiesMapLocal;
}
```

}

**pax-cdi**

```
@ApplicationScoped
@Named
public class DefaultApiImpl implements DefaultApi {

@Override
    public Response login(String userAgent, String username, String password, UriInfo uriInfo) {

PropertiesUtil.getProperty(SecurityConfig.TOKEN_SIG_SECRET);

}
```

**cfg file**

you can have karaf_home/etc/ca.esc.pbm.frontend.security.cfg
holding a value
signatureSecret=my-secret